# Form Validation on Array name fields - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a dynamic form to add rows. The form lets the users to add transactions and submit it. I want to validate only the transaction numbers before inserting them into DB. I have to check

1. If the transaction field is empty or not
2. If the transaction already exists in the transactions table (if yes : display message transaction already exists. Please remove row. If no: proceed to DB insertion)

View part:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12  ">

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php
echo form_error("Transaction_number[]");
?> 

<?php echo form_open('payment_refund/refund_form/'); ?>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id='tbl' class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Transaction_number</th> 
      <th>Order_number</th>
      <th>Amount_paid</th>
      <th>Transaction_date</th>
      <th>Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='Transaction_number[]' value="<?php echo set_value('Transaction_number[]'); ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Order_number[]' value="<?php echo set_value('Order_number[]'); ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type='number' name='Amount_paid[]' value="<?php echo set_value('Amount_paid[]'); ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type='date' name='Transaction_date[]' value="<?php echo set_value('Transaction_date[]'); ?>" /></td>
      <td><input type='button' value='Remove' class='rmv'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'><input type='button' value='+Add Row' id='add_row'></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
      var row="<tr> <td><input type='text' name='Transaction_number[]'></td> <td><input type='text' name='Order_number[]'></td> <td><input type='number' name='Amount_paid[]'></td> <td><input type='date' name='Transaction_date[]'></td> <td><input type='button' value='Remove' class='rmv'></td> </tr>";
      $("#tbl tbody").append(row);
    });
    
    $("body").on("click",".rmv",function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
  });
</script>
        <!-- Insert a check to see if any transaction details are entered before submit -->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
    
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

</div>
```

Controller Part:

```
    class Refund_form extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct(array('stu')); 
        
        $this->load->model('payment_refund/refund_form_model','',TRUE);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->helper('array');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $Transaction_number = $this->input->post('Transaction_number');

        for($i = 0; $i < count($Transaction_number); $i++) 
        {            
            $tran = $Transaction_number[$i];
            
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($tran, 'Transaction', 'required');
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
            {
                echo "All went well <br/>"; // insertion into DB for all table data fetched from view is done here
            }
        else
            {
                echo "All is NOT well <br/>";
            }

        
    public function add()
    {
        $this->drawHeader("Refund form - Add");
        
        $this->load->view('payment_refund/refund_form_view');
        $this->drawFooter();
    }
```

Other methods that i tried to validate the form

```
`$formrules = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'Transaction_number[]',
                'label' => 'the transsaction field',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ),
         
         );
         $this->form_validation->set_rules($formrules);
 
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {return true; } //DB insertion
        else
        { return false; } `
```

DB insertion is done as below

```
for($i=0;$i<count($Transaction_number);$i++){
    $data[] = [

        'tracking_id' => $tracking_id, 
        'trans_id' => $Transaction_number[$i],
        'order_id' => $Order_number[$i],
        'amount' => $Amount_paid[$i],
        'date_of_trans' => $Transaction_date[$i],
        

        ];
    }

    //inser_batch

    $response=$this->db->insert_batch('refund_transaction_details',$data);
    if($response==true){
        echo "Records Saved Successfully";
    }
    else{
        echo "Insert error !";
    }
```

Comment: first of all remove $this->load->library('form_validation'); from loop as you have already loaded library and obviously this shouldn't be in loop, second no need to loop over transaction numbers fields in loop you can use one line for this $this->form_validation->set_rules('Transaction_number[]', 'Transaction', 'required');
and to check if already added in DB, you need to add hooks in same validation rule where you can check through query or model

Comment: for hooks (custom rules) https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html